# In Minecraft, can I teleport an entity by a scoreboard value?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For example

```
/tp @e[type=Chicken] ~ ~ ~-{Score_Gravity}
```

Is it possible to do this? If not, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

If the scoreboard objective is `Gravity` then the command will look something like this:

```
/tp @e[type=Chicken,score_Gravity_min=X,score_Gravity=Y] ~ ~ ~
```

`X` = Minimum Score
`Y` = Maximum Score

Comment: Very good first answer, welcome to the site. I did some formatting on it and removed unnecessary bits. Make sure to check out the [tour] of the site as well, it explains the workings of the site for new users as SE is/works different from most other sites.